# How can I restrict a user in an AD environment only to have vpn access but no directory share rights?

Tags: vpn, firewall, active-directory, restrictions, domain-security

I'm trying to restrict an AD account to only have vpn access rights but no domain user rights. Can it be done or should I try something out of windows server's boundaries?

We are using a Fortigate firewall where we defined this user to only have access to the 8080 port after connecting with vpn authenticated by the AD. If I leave the settings in the current form, would that user be able to access the domain user shares?

Comment: Thanks. I haven't managed any servers since nearly 5 years. I'm having a hard time to even remember such basic concepts. If you can post your comment as an answer, I'm going to select it as the solution and vote it up.

Comment: If you want to post an answer to this question I encourage you to do that.  **Just don't give me credit for it.**  The comment I made was not good enough to be considered an actual answer and I want no credit for it.